# how can i update the quantity values in my dictionary ios Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, nsdictionary, arrayofarrays

i've a array of object in my app that is passed to another VC called restaurantViewController the value is stored in restMenu and now the problem is that whenever i scroll the UITableView the ItemQuantityCell value is always reused to 0 which is default value in my restMenu how can i update value in my restMenu so i can pass it to checkoutVC with correct value for my ItemQuantityCell. 
my plist from where the data is coming is as follows

[image: ResturantFile.plist]

here is my code

```
var restMenu = [[String:Any]]()

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! RestaurantItemViewCell

    cell.delegate = self as? TableViewCellDelegate

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.none

    //assign item name to cell
    let selectedDictName = restMenu[indexPath.row] as NSDictionary
    print("the selected dict ", selectedDictName)
    cell.itemNameLabel.text = selectedDictName.value(forKey: "ItemName") as? String

    // assign item price to cell
    let selectedDictPrice = restMenu[indexPath.row] as NSDictionary
    cell.itemPriceLabel.text = "Price: \(selectedDictPrice.value(forKey: "ItemPrice") as! String)"

    // assign item quantity to cell
    let selectedDictQuant = restMenu[indexPath.row] as NSDictionary
    cell.itemQuantityLabel.text = selectedDictQuant.value(forKey: "ItemQuant") as? String

}
```

Comment: Why are you using `NSDictionary` in Swift? Where do you attempt to update the quantity?  You should start by parsing your JSON into a proper `struct` or `class` rather than simply using `[String:Any]`.  Look at `Codable`

Comment: i'm newbee someone suggested me but now i've updated my code as suggested to PPL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your plist, **ItemQuant** is zero always and you are assigning the same value in `cell.itemQuantityLabel.text` so it will be always zero.

Next, please do changes in your code, do not use **NSStuff** in **Swift**.

Update your `cellForRowAt indexPath` like below

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! RestaurantItemViewCell
    cell.delegate = self as? TableViewCellDelegate
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.none

    //assign item name to cell
    let dict = restMenu[indexPath.row]
    print("the selected dict ", dict)

    cell.itemNameLabel.text = dict["ItemName"] as! String
    cell.itemPriceLabel.text = dict["ItemPrice"] as! String
    cell.itemQuantityLabel.text = dict["ItemQuant"] as! String

    return cell
}
```

Hope this works for you.

FYI. Above code is not tested. It is for your reference only.

**Note**
Wherever you want to update the quantity of item
Get the index on which you want to update the quantity and do as follows

```
restMenu[index]["ItemQuant"] = "2" // index is you will get somehow & 2 is just for example you can do what you want there.
```

**UPDATE**

As per your last comment, this is suggestion.

Instead of Dictionary Structure, create appropriate model classes, and parse the plist, your `cellForRowAt indexPath` will be changed, Your **ItemQuant** must be **Int** value. Pass the `restMenu` object to other `ViewController` and update its **ItemQuant**. If you navigate back just reload your tableview data. It will show you changes in **ItemQuant**.

Comment: the code is running fine but the problem is still there

Comment: no it is still doing the same stuff as previously. when i scroll the UITableView the values reuse the default values i was thinking if i could replace the values of previous ItemQuant with new values when i do increment of decrement in Quantity . but  iam not able to do that

Comment: no it is still doing the same stuff as previously. when i scroll the UITableView the values reuse the default values i was thinking if i could replace the values of previous ItemQuant with new values when i do increment of decrement in Quantity . but  iam not able to do that

Comment: it will use default because you are assigning it like this, cell.itemQuantityLabel.text = dict["ItemQuant"] as! String, it is getting value from the dictionary itself, you should update this line accordingly to update the label value

Comment: how can i do that i'm searching for this for one hour but still got nothing.

Comment: Dear we can give you suggestion here, you have to do code yourself, please share your exact requirement I will suggest you

Comment: i've itemNames, price and quantity when i select restaurant in my viewcontroller it check the selected cell title and then match it with the dictionary and pass the data to next VC and there i've to show the data in cell with item name, price and quantity and if i update the quantity on one cell the same data cell quantity should updated in corresponding. without using the same default quantity value

Comment: Cannot convert value of type '(Any) -> Int' to expected argument type '(UnboundedRange_) -> ()' . there is a error